# Invalid column name error when Saving Selected Text From Drop Down Box into Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ado.net

Platform used : Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (C#)
Database : SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

I want to get the text from the drop down and put it into database table. I am getting error saying

> Invalid column name 'Type'.

though column is present in database table.

```
da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into tblProductMaster ([Name],[Type],[Height],[Width],[Length],[Price]) values( @Name , @Type , @Height , @Width , @Length , @Price )", con);

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = ddlType.SelectedItem.ToString();
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Height", SqlDbType.Float).Value = float.Parse(txtHeight.Text);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Width", SqlDbType.Float).Value = float.Parse(txtWidth.Text);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Length", SqlDbType.Float).Value = float.Parse(txtLength.Text);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.SmallMoney).Value = int.Parse(txtPrice.Text);

da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: try writing this da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into tblProductMaster([Name],[Size],Height,Width,[Length],Price) values (@Name,@Size,@Height,@Width,@Length,@Price)", con);

Comment: Same Error "Invalid Column Name Size"

Comment: Need to change check column name

Comment: Column Name Changed From "Size" to "Type" But Same Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are using a [SQL Server reserved word ("Size")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and you have not properly encapsulated it in your `INSERT` statement.

Try this:

```
da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into tblProductMaster ([Name], [Size], [Height], [Width], [Length], [Price]) values(@Name, @Size, @Height, @Width, @Length, @Price)", con);
```

Notice the `[` & `]` around the column names... this will tell SQL Server to treat them as columns.

**WARNING:** I *highly* recommend you change these column names if you can.  Using reserved words of any product is very poor database design and will continue to cause you problems and/or extra work.  Better to fix it sooner than later.

Comment: Column Name Changed From "Size" to "Type" But Same Error

Answer (score 0):

@Sagar try this

```
string strCmd = @"insert into tblProductMaster ([Name], [Size], [Height], [Width], [Length], [Price]) values(@Name, @Size, @Height, @Width, @Length, @Price)";
```

Then

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, ddlSize.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());  

da.InsertCommand = cmd;
```